# Mongodb:how to copy collection with different address in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two  Mongodb with same schema  and two different addresses respectively are `test/prod`. Now i want to copy  some data in one collection to another same collection with different address.

I'm going to write code to connect both Mongodb; traverse one; find suitable data and then insert to another. Is there a better way to do this?

I'm new to Mongodb and don't know how. Please help ,thanks a lot

Comment: You might find your answer in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17998101/1072229)