# How to populate Rails app with existing mongo database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a database "market" with collection "users". I want to create a Rails app and populate it with an existing data. So, I have a few questions:
1. Which gem better use? Mongoid or maybe mongo_mapper
2. What to write in config to indicate with which db to work?
3. How to bind User model with collection.

I tried to write the following in mongoid.yml

```
database: market
```

but it didn't work.
Please, describe me how to make it step by step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb

Comment: What have you searched until now? Have you followed any tutorial or read any documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: mongorestore -d market_development -c userdump/some_collection.bson