# MongoDB find today's records

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo shell, how would I filter records that have been added today (or on a specific date)? I have no specific field of the timestamp of new records, but I guess it can be restored from ObjectID.

Comment: @cubbuk I think that `$where` was not yet implemented for mongo shell that days.

Comment: @thanasisp $where requires table scan as it needs to evaluate where expression on each record, thus has low performance

Comment: @cubbuk of course it does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

we can use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/where/#where)

```
db.collection.find(
   { $where: "this._id.getTimestamp() >= ISODate('2017-02-25')" }
)
```

To get documents for today, or better say from last midnight:

```
db.collection.find( { $where: function() { 
    today = new Date(); //
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return (this._id.getTimestamp() >= today)
} } );
```

of course it is much faster to have an indexed timestamp field or to follow the approach with the calculation of an ObjectID for the start date and compare _id against it, as _id is indexed too.

Answer (score 4):

To get all the records from today:

```
var startOfToday = new Date();
startOfToday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
// creates ObjectId() from date:
var _id = Math.floor(startOfToday.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";

> db.collection("records")
    .find( { _id: { $gte: ObjectId(_id) } });
```

To get all the records from the given time period (*example: yesterday*):

```
var yesterdayStart = new Date();
yesterdayStart.setDate(yesterdayStart.getDate() - 1);
yesterdayStart.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var startId = Math.floor(yesterdayStart.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";

var yesterdayEnd = new Date();
yesterdayEnd.setDate(yesterdayEnd.getDate() - 1);
yesterdayEnd.setHours(23,59,59,999);
var endId = Math.floor(yesterdayEnd.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";

> db.collection("records")
    .find( { _id: { 
                    $gte: ObjectId(startId),
                    $lte: ObjectId(endId)
                  } 
           }
    );
```