# MongoDB: How to get timestamp and ObjectID from newest document in collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to get last created documents in collection and return their objectID and timestamps. For example if yesterday I created 10 documents I would like to return them with db.collection and then

```
const lastTimeStamp = will be the timestamp from the last created element

const lastTimeStampArray = will be array of timestamps from yesterdays records

const lastObjectId = will be ObjectID of last created document

const lastObjectIdsArray = array of last objectIds
```

I am using:

Comment: You can simply return the last documents sorted by your timestamp: `db.collection.find().sort({ timestamp: -1 }).limit(n)` such that `timestamp` is your date object and `n` is the number of documents you wish to return.

Comment: Yes but how do I extract timestamp of it?
I tried:
lastDoc = db.collection.find().sort({ timestamp: -1 }).limit(n);
let docID = lastDoc._id; (undefined)
timestamp = docID.getTimestamp(); (err)

Comment: Note that `find()` returns a cursor, so you will naturally iterate through the result (e.g. get the last 10 timestamps) or use`lastDoc[0]` from your example. If you only need a single document, use `findOne()` instead. This will return a single document. So your code will look like this: `const lastDoc = db.collection.findOne().sort({ timestamp: -1 }); const docId = lastDoc._id; const lastTimestamp = lastDoc.timestamp; ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB's `_id` field has info about date stored in itself. The timestamp is contained in the first 4 bytes of a mongoDB id.

- You can use [ObjectId.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/) function to get time from `_id` of a document.
- Sorting on an _id field that stores ObjectId values is roughly equivalent to sorting by creation time.

For you question:

```
// To get lastTimeStamp
db.collection.find().sort({ '_id': -1}).limit(1).forEach( 
   function(doc){ 
      lastTimeStamp = doc._id.getTimestamp(); 
   }
)


// to get lastObjectId
db.collection.find().sort({ '_id': -1}).limit(1).forEach( 
   function(doc){ 
       lastObjectId = doc._id; 
   }
)
```

Now, to get all records inserted yesterday might be a bit of hard work. You need to extract all records inserted yesterday and from that you need to extract information you need.

```
// to get lastTimeStampArray and lastObjectIdsArray
var yesterdayStart = new Date();
yesterdayStart.setDate(yesterdayStart.getDate() - 1);
yesterdayStart.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var startId = Math.floor(yesterdayStart.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";

var yesterdayEnd = new Date();
yesterdayEnd.setDate(yesterdayEnd.getDate() - 1);
yesterdayEnd.setHours(23,59,59,999);
var endId = Math.floor(yesterdayEnd.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";

var lastTimeStampArray = [];
var lastObjectIdsArray = [];

db.collection("records")
   .find( { _id: { 
                $gte: ObjectId(startId),
                $lte: ObjectId(endId)
              } 
       }
).forEach(
     function(doc){
         lastObjectIdsArray.push(doc._id);
         lastTimeStampArray.push(doc._id.getTimestamp());
});
```

These are mongo shell commands you can write your node.js accordingly.

Comment: Some source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456375/mongodb-find-todays-records

Answer (score 2):

You can get last inserted record with timestamp using the following:

```
db.collection.find().sort({ '_id': -1 }).limit(1).forEach(
     function(doc){
         print("record:"+doc._id.getTimestamp());
})
```

***_id*** is the Mongodb objectID