# Create copy of MongoDB Atlas database through API

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

**Context**
We're currently trying to copy a database called **DatabaseA** on an M2 cluster. We're trying to create backups of our cluster by cloning our database into a new database called **DatabaseB** every 24 hours using MongoDB Atlas.

We've already looked into the following links:

- https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodump-example-copy-clone-database

But we have no idea how to implement this.

How should we approach this?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 approaches.

The best way (in my eyes) is to use Mongo Atlas Datalake.
They have a guide here showing how to [copy from mongo to S3](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/automated-continuous-data-copying-from-mongodb-to-s3/) continuously but the same approach can also be used to copy from one MongoDB database to another.

To summarise and supplement the docs linked the rough approach is:

1. Create a [DataLake](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/datalake/tutorial/deploy/) and link DataLake to MongoDB database in Atlas
2. Create a [Scheduled trigger](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/triggers/scheduled-triggers/) to run every 24 hours.
   *See pseudocode snippet below*

```html
exports = async function() {
  const movies = context.services
    .get("DataLake0")
    .db("Database0")
    .collection("Collection0");
    
    const pipeline = [
      {
            $match: {}
      }, {
    "$out": {
      "atlas": {
        "projectId": "111111111111111111111111",
        "clusterName": "<YourOtherCluster>",
        "db": "<YourOtherDB>",
        "coll": "<CollectionName>"
      }
    }
}
   ];
  return movies.aggregate(pipeline);
};
```

I did this mostly through the UI but there's a way to do it programmatically shown here: [DataLake API docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/datalake/reference/api/datalakes-api/)

Another approach which is recommended in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554877/4244112)

(*Not directly what you're asking about the API*; only mentioning it since it's related)

The approach is to use:

- `mongodump --host="mongodb0.example.com"`

then

- `mongorestore --host="mongodb0.example.com`

See linked question or [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/) for more details.