# Mongorestore a single collection through stdin output

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, mongodb-tools

I would like to copy a MongoDB collection to another database in a single command line using the standard output.
I don't want to dump the entire database.
The target collection will have a different name from the copy.

Here is my command :

```
> mongodump -h=HOST -d=db1 -c=from_coll --archive --gzip | mongorestore -h=HOST --nsInclude=db2.target_coll --archive --gzip

  writing db1.from_coll to an archive on stdout
  preparing collections to restore from
  done dumping db1.from_coll (100000 documents)
  0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

The mongodump part seems to work well.
But we have `(0 document(s) restored successfully)`
Why the mongorestore doesn't copy the data in the target collection as expected ?

Comment: option `--gzip` is useless, because you don't store the file anyway. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077465/3027266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--nsInclude` option filters the input data.  Since the bson data being passed from mongodump does not include any documents from `db2.target_coll`, nothing is restored.

Use the `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo` to rename a collection with mongorestore.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to backup a collection using mongodump but didn't work, I don't know why, then I changed and used [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/) and [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) like this, and it works fine.

mongoexport --uri="mongodb://host:port/fooDatabase"  --collection=fooCollection --out=fooCollection.json

mongoimport --uri="mongodb://host:port/fooDatabase" --collection=newFooCollection --file=fooCollection.json --mode=upsert