# Looking to find a Best way to copy a collection from one server to another server with two different mongodb versions

Tags: mongodb, collections, copy

I need to copy a collection (large data size, around 100 GB) from one database server to another server. Also both server follows two different mongodb versions.

```
source server - lower mongodb version

destination server - latest mongodb version
```

Is there any best and faster way to make it done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `mongodump ... | mongorestore ...`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb/67077465#67077465

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I followed that, but its taking hours and hours to copy large collection.

Comment: I don't think there are any alternatives. You could try to copy all files from `dbPath` (while source and destination mongoDB are stopped) and then follow the [upgrade procedure](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-upgrade-standalone/)