# Copy a huge bunch of documents one collection to another in mongosh

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to copy a million document in a collection to another colletion.

```
> db.source_collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { db.dest_collection.insertOne(doc)});
```

This works fine. but I wonder it might cause any trouble to operating Database if I loop a million documents.

Can I give a sleep while looping in mongh shell?
Is there any better solution for this?

Please advise me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb/67077465#67077465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bulkWrite()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/bulkWrite/) rather than insertOne , it will reduce your time significantly.

```
var bulk = db.dest_collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.source_collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  bulk.insert(doc);
  counter++;
  if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.dest_collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  }
});
if (counter % 1000 != 0) {
  bulk.execute();
}
```

In this code  For every 1000 documents, the code executes the bulk operation using the execute() method, and then re-initializes the bulk operation. Finally, after all documents are processed, the code executes the remaining bulk operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the aggregation [$out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#-out--aggregation-) stage, you can copy the documents directly on the server and avoid the network round trip to the client.

```
db.source_collection.aggregate([{$out:"destination_collection"}])
```

Comment: It works and save much time for me. Thanks a lot. @Joe