How can I use mongodump in batches for collection which has millions of records
I am trying to migrate DB which has lot of collections and each collections have millions of documents.
I am using mongodump and mongorestore. how can I force mongodump to dump lets say 10000 documents in every mongodump operation and restore same amount of documents in monogrestore?
Is there any better alternative?
I am thinking of sorting the documents in my filter and keep track of every 10000th document and use $gt than lastID

Do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb/67077465#67077465 Importing "millions" of document should not cause big trouble.
